# How to use nonce in style-src CSP

Tags: css, content-security-policy

I have a sample code like

This is the end
As I understand CSP I should be able to add this to the CSP header and the inline style is allowed. Instead I am getting and error message indicating that 
nonce or hash is required.

Report Only] Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src localhost DC3VDIITG0345.global.ldap.wan 'nonce-8IBTHwOdqNKAWeKl7plt8g=='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-ZBTj5RHLnrF+IxdRZM2RuLfjTJQXNSi7fLQHr09onfY='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

Is the format incorrect?